# Extract folders' contents to the parent folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I have multiple folders inside one folder, I want to move all the contents of these folders up to the parent ( basically like extracting compressed files )

so what's the easiest way to accomplish this ?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not looking for CMD solution but there good answers there

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in explorer - unless there is something special about the file names so you can search and match them ...

Comment: @DavidPostill exactly the answer with the search is the simplest, thanks for the assist

Comment: [Windows - How to move all files in subfolders to a parent folder?](http://superuser.com/a/746652)